# Here maps in more than one app on the same device

Tags: android, navigation, here-api

We are having an issue with HERE maps.

We are getting "UNKNOW ERROR" while initializing here maps when there is another app using HERE maps in the same device.

In other words, we are not able to run HERE maps in more than one app on the same device. We have separate credentials for both the app.

My question is how can I run more than one app using HERE maps
on the same device?

Initialization code:

```
 private void initHereMaps() {
        final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        ProgressDialogUtility.showProgressDialog(context, "Initializing map...");
        mapFragment.init(this, new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {

                //if no error occurs
                if (error == Error.NONE) {



                } else {
                    //if error occurred during initialization, display toast message
                    L.e("Map initialization error " + error);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Map initialization error " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem and it is in fact supported to have multiple apps running using the HERE SDK and sharing the same common map data (i.e. shared disk cache).

Are you properly including the global `MapService` as outlined in the [Embedding the Map Service documentation](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-service.html)? You can also try the instructions on the same page to use an isolated disk cache in both of your apps to see if this helps.

If the above seems OK, could you please print out the additional information from the `OnEngineInitListener#Error` enum and provide it? You can use the APIs `getDetails()`, `getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Yeah, Its working fine when I use isolated disk cache and custom Map service. But is there a way to run multiple apps parallelly without disk cache?

Comment: If you are using the global `MapService` (e.g. the first service snippet in the link above), you should not need to use the isolated disk cache and the shared cache should be located at getExternalStorageDirectory()/.here-maps (on most devices sdcard/.here-maps). If you are using this global service entry and still having issues, please provide additional Error details using APIs above. Also, you should make sure you are not running a cache cleaning app on your device [More Info](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/development-tips.html)